Eclipse CDT (C++): Organize Imports mangling file comments
Until recently, Eclipse CDT did a fairly good job of organizing imports (Ctrl+shift+O) and Add Include (Ctrl+shift+N).  It would find undefined labels, search for matching headers, and insert them after the other #include files.  But recently, it's started mangling my file header comments in the process.  Example:
/*=============================================================================
 Copyright(c) 2024, All Rights Reserved.
 Company Name
 ==============================================================================*/

#pragma once

/****************************   Include Files        **************************/

#include <tasks/Recorder/recorder_test.hpp>

gets mangled to:
#include <tasks/Recorder/recorder.hpp>

 Copyright(c) 2024, All Rights Reserved.
 Company Name
 ==============================================================================*/

#pragma once

/****************************   Include Files        **************************/

#include <tasks/Recorder/recorder_test.hpp>

Any ideas why this has started?  Was it the update from 2024-03 to 2024-06?  Is there a way to fix this?  Not seeing anything pertinent in the preferences, nor on Google Search.

This really isn't a programming question, more like a topic for https://github.com/eclipse-cdt/cdt/discussions .
